# Gradle build tools 4.1.0 failing sync in Android Studio when there is a lintCheck dependency

Tags: android, gradle, lint, android-studio-4.1

We have an Android multi module project with custom lint checks and we've been trying to move to Android gradle build tools **4.1.0**, but Android Studio 4.1.0 gradle sync keeps failing.

Say we have two modules (plus some irrelevant "library" modules):

- `app` (main app module)
- `lintchecks` (custom lint rules)

`app` uses the custom `lintchecks` module, in `app/build.gradle`:

```
  lintChecks project(":lintchecks")
```

Now, say there is some custom plugin (e.g. in `buildSrc`) or configuration using the combination of `subprojects` and `tasks.whenTaskAdded`.
For example, in `./build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
   tasks.whenTaskAdded { 
     // content not important
   }
}
```

There's nothing special in the `lintcheck` configuration. For example in `lintchecks/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:27.1.0"
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation "com.android.tools.lint:lint:27.1.0"
    testImplementation "com.android.tools.lint:lint-tests:27.1.0"
    testImplementation "com.android.tools:testutils:27.1.0"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Lint-Registry-v2": "com.company.lintrules.IssueRegistry")
    }
}
```

It has been failing all the time on Android Studio sync with error similar to:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':lintrules'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin'.
   > Gradle#projectsEvaluated(Action) on build 'MyCompanyBuild' cannot be executed in the current context.
```

### In Summary

It seems the issue is the combination of **Android Studio 4.1.0** + build gradle tools **4.1.0** + **`lintCheck()`** + **`tasks.whenTaskAdded {}`**.

### What I've tried

- different plugins in `lintrules/build.xml`, e.g. `maven-publish`, `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm`, same error result
- different way to declare the plugin, e.g. `plugins { id (...) }` versus `apply plugin: '...'`, same error result
- older versions of lint dependencies
- removing `lintCheck`, or removing `tasks.whenTaskAdded`, or downgrading to gradle build tools `4.0.1`, any of these makes it work again
- running any command on terminal, outside of Android Studio, it works fine, issue seems to be only on the A.S. sync operation.

### Question

Anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: Someone pointed me towards https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170656529
The way to by pass this is to test by `System.getProperty("idea.active") != "true"` and bypass lint checks for the IDE only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is being reported under ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170656529

The way to workaround this for now is to skip the logic causing issues on the IDE testing for `idea.active` system property:

```
if(System.getProperty("idea.active") != "true"){
  tasks.whenTaskAdded {
    (...)
  }
}
```

(Thanks Jerry for finding the ticket)

Comment: Where does this if statement go?

Comment: Thank you for saving us couple of days of work with this answer. We had the same problem when `tasks.withType()` was called, not `tasks.whenTaskAdded`.